# Css3, show or hide child div when mouse hovers over parent div

Tags: css, user-interface

I have two divs like

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

If I want to slide in the child div from bottom when the mouse hovers over the parent.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

here is demo **http://jsfiddle.net/ww2zY/2**

```
.parent {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:170px;
    ;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.child {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
    transform:translateY(100px);
    -webkit-transform:translateY(100px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(100px);
    transition:all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 1s linear;
}
.parent:hover .child {
    transform:translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(0px);
}
```

Comment: Nice bro, but the child element has to be hidden and should be like poping in from bottom could you please do it, i'm noob to css

Comment: Thanks bro, that helped allot, but there is too much isn't it

Comment: you can contol speed in 1s to 0.5s and so on

Comment: I'm not gonna call you bro, but thank you. Helped a lot this morning.

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS3 keyframes

http://jsfiddle.net/27N57/

```
@keyframes "move" {
 from {
    top: 200px;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
 }
 to {
    top: 30px;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
 }

}
```

Comment: even this is good buddy, lot to learn about css3 yet
thanks for all the info guys

Answer (score 0):

You can use tooltip js for this problem to solve.

Comment: Thanks but i want purely with css3 transitions.